Broadcasting smart contract transactions to owner wallets of Safe
I followed the steps on the answer for Deploying contracts from safe wallet and I'm able to use protocol-kit to create, sign and execute transactions. This will work if I want to perform signing using these scripts.
However, I can't broadcast these transactions to the other wallets so they can sign this from the UI.
I believe we have to use the ApiKit for this. Here's what I'm using as script

  const apiKit = new SafeApiKit({
    chainId: 47646289n,
    txServiceUrl: "http://localhost:8000/txs/api", // http:localhost:8000/txs don't work
  });

  const txData = createDeployContractTransaction(BYTECODE, 0n);
  const tx = await protocolKitOwner.createTransaction({
    transactions: [
      {
        to: CREATECALL_CONTRACT_ADDRESS,
        data: txData,
        value: 0n,
        operation: 1,
      },
    ],
  });
  const txHash = await protocolKitOwner.getTransactionHash(tx);
  const txResponse = await protocolKitOwner.approveTransactionHash(txHash);

  const safeTxHash = await protocolKitOwner.getTransactionHash(
    tx
  );
  const signature = await protocolKitOwner.signHash(safeTxHash);
  
  await apiKit.proposeTransaction({
    safeAddress: SAFE_ADDRESS,
    safeTransactionData: txData, // Contract creation byte code for the contract to deploy
    safeTxHash,
    senderSignature: signature.data,
    senderAddress: SIGNER_ADDRESS
  });
  // await protocolKitOwner.signTransaction({transaction: tx})
  // await protocolKitOwner.executeTransaction(tx) // Successfully executes if Safe has a single owner

The errors I get on proposeTransaction line are
Error: Unprocessable Entity
    at sendRequest (/Users/arpitkarnatak/Desktop/personal/node-pg/node_modules/@safe-global/api-kit/dist/src/utils/httpRequests.js:56:11)


Thanks again for your question.
I could not verify your code 100%, as I don't know what your createDeployContractTransaction function is doing.
But you had some small errors in which data you were handing over to the API Kit.
Here is a corrected and commented code:
const txData = createDeployContractTransaction(BYTECODE, 0n);

// you are creating a SafeTransaction correctly here:
const tx = await protocolKitOwner.createTransaction({
  transactions: [
    {
      to: CREATECALL_CONTRACT_ADDRESS,
      data: txData,
      value: '0', // this should be a string
      operation: 1,
    },
  ],
});
})

const txHash = await protocolKitOwner.getTransactionHash(tx)

// you don't need this call here, so you can remove it.
// (Approving transactions with a hash is a different method)
const txResponse = await protocolKitOwner.approveTransactionHash(txHash)

const safeTxHash = await protocolKitOwner.getTransactionHash(tx)
const signature = await protocolKitOwner.signHash(safeTxHash)

await apiKit.proposeTransaction({
  safeAddress: SAFE_ADDRESS,
  // The next line is where you were handing over the wrong data
  // You have to pass the SafeTransactionData object of the SafeTransaction you created
  safeTransactionData: tx.data, 
  safeTxHash,
  senderSignature: signature.data,
  senderAddress: SIGNER_ADDRESS
})

I have to admit that our documentation around these functions is not the best, so we will improve this for the future.

Thank you Valentin, this is exactly what I did wrong. Appreciate it

Try using the protocolOwnerKit's signer address instead of a random SIGNER_ADDRESS if any in proposeTransaction() function.
Furthermore, I have a working code for the your usecase which I built few weeks ago. Hope that helps you.
Here's the gist - https://gist.github.com/pankajjagtapp/db3e30e5ce0028b285177491c42b5eed

Thanks for jumping in here, Pankaj!

Thanks Pankaj, I was using the encodedData instead of the safeTransaction.data in proposeTransaction.
